# WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost

Tags: javascript

I am using https://github.com/JeremyHeleine/Photo-Sphere-Viewer to render multiple photo spheres and getting the following error,

> WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost.

Here is the snippet that seems to be causing the problem:

```
 var max_width = 2048;
 if (isWebGLSupported()) {
   var canvas_tmp = document.createElement('canvas');
   var ctx_tmp = canvas_tmp.getContext('webgl');
   max_width = ctx_tmp.getParameter(ctx_tmp.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE);
 }
```

Any ideas on how to kill the error and only render the context once?

Comment: When are you running that code, exactly?

Comment: The error that is thrown might have the origin at this snipped, but the reason is, that you call this code too many times. So you need to check where you call this code and why you call it multiple times.

Comment: It is being called multiple times because i am rendering multiple photo spheres on the same page. Is there a way to limit the times it gets called so this does not happen?

Comment: Have the same problem with 3d google streetview, in my angular application i have many google streetview block on the same page, but only one is visible (exists in dom) in the given time, it seems they create canvas elements and doesn't remove them after streetview is destroyed (or i should do this programmaticcally).

Comment: well it seems to me like the only way to work around would be to reuse a webgl contex, maybe you would need to animate the spheres on the same canvas? perhaps you could do rendering work on one invisible canvas, then printing it on a visible canvas, rendering the next photo, printing it on the next canvas and so on, its an efficiency nightmare but might work